# Exponentiation of non-diagonalizable matrix $M=\begin{bmatrix} 12 & 1\\ -9 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let
>
> $$M=\begin{bmatrix}
> 12 & 1\\
> -9 & 6
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Find an expression for $M^n$.

I am not sure how to do it since $M$ is non-diagonalizable. Thank you for any help!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1898710/339790

Comment: See case 2 of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1538095/265466.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $X=M-9I$. Then $X^2=0$ and you may evaluate the binomial expansion of $M^n=(9I+X)^n$ easily.

Comment: is there a name for this technique?

Comment: @Tanner $X$ is called a *nilpotent matrix* in linear algebra.